# winforms .net c# - external program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, external

I have c# .net (winforms) program with button. I also have another console program in c++ (it takes as argument text file and change it). I wand to something like that: I press button (in c# program is stored path to txt file), the C++ program is executed but user dont see it (i dont want open for example command line in new window). Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe, you should have a look at the `Process.Start()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx

In the `ProcessStartInfo` you can pass to this method, you can specify that no window should be opened.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(pathToExeFile)
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    // ...
});
```